Late 1950s or 1960s childrens/YA series - the children have a secret spaceship, go to Mars, and meet a Martian child
I am looking for a 1950s or 1960s YA series of books about a group of children who have a secret spaceship. They go to Mars, where they meet a Martian child. In one of the books, just as they are leaving Mars, a war breaks out. When they return in a later novel, their Martian friend has become King of Mars. This is not the Dunn series. The series had multiple books.
